# Errors migrating subversion repository

Tags: svn, freebsd, svnadmin

I'm having trouble migrating repositories from an old server running Ubuntu 12.04 to a new server running FreeNAS 9.3 (BSD-based) using the svnadmin dump and load commands. When I try to load the repositories, I get E200029 errors about not being able to open the rep-cache database or perform atomic initilization, shown in this [screenshot](http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/filedata/fetch?filedataid=415), and nothing populates the repository. I have read through the svn-book manual and researched solutions online, re-dumped a repository, tried doing this as both root and the subversion:subversion accounts, and populated the repository with empty directories, but I haven't been able to figure out the problem yet.

My setup is a multi-project repository with subfolders for individual projects using the tag/branch/trunk structure under that project's folder (given a project number), that looks something like the following.

```
$ svn list file:///var/svn/multi-project-repo
project-A/
project-B/
$ svn list file:///var/svn/multi-project-repo/project-A
trunk/
branches/
tags/
$
```

There are about 30 project folders. The current Ubuntu server is using svnadmin --version 1.6.17 while the new FreeNAS server is using svnadmin --version 1.8.13. If it is a problem, I'm not sure how to resolve these differences since Ubuntu doesn't have a more recent version in the package repository.

I used the following command to create a dump file of the entire repository, without any particular flags or filtering. I'm just trying to replicate the same structure on the new server. This was run as root in a cron job on the Ubuntu server.

```
svnadmin dump --quiet /home/svn/repos/projects > /home/svn/migrate/projects.dmp
```

Then, I installed subversion in a FreeNAS server BSD jail (pkg install subversion) and created the "projects" repository. Initially, it was just an empty repository, which failed to load, but since there are only 30 subdirectories I also tried populating the repository with empty project directories including branch/tag/truck subdirectories using an SVN client on my Windows box and then trying to load the repository from the dump through a shell into the FreeNAS jail, as root. That failed to load, too, with the same error.

```
svnadmin load /var/svn/repos/projects < /var/svn/dump/projects.dmp
```

Should the absolute paths of the original and new repositories be the same? Any ideas what else I can try or what might be causing the issues?

Thanks.

Note: in my research, I did cross-post this question in a subversion-specific forum, but haven't gotten any responses.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the errors likely stemmed from a incorrectly linked library. Using the following when creating the repositories corrected the problem and allowed me to load the repositories fine.

```
# svnadmin create --pre-1.6-compatible /path/to/repos
```